# Difference between 2 array results from chrome console

Tags: javascript, jquery

could someone explain to me the difference between these 2 results visible from the chrome console? They are 2 arrays

```
result 1: []

result 2: (50) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},

Result content 1: []
0: {date: 1666266087, value: 1.3093172311782837, bullet: false}
1: {date: 1666266092, value: 1.3266782760620117, bullet: false}
2: {date: 1666266097, value: 1.330295205116272, bullet: false}
3: {date: 1666266102, value: 1.3346354961395264, bullet: false}
...

Result content 2: (50) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, { …}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} , {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, { …}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} , {…}, {…}]
0: {date: 1579906800000, value: 0.7829438782435978}
1: {date: 1579906801000, value: 0.5718284362450616}
2: {date: 1579906802000, value: 0.5449734709965754}
3: {date: 1579906803000, value: 0.9682872211590137}
...
```

On the second I can, for example, get the length through arr2.length while the first returns 0 to me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show what objects you are logging or something?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: The first one was empty *when it was logged* but then afterwards it had data added. When you expanded the logged value, you see the latest state.